# order of zeroes for bounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Looking over this, I don't understand why after $|H(0)|\leq lim_{z\rightarrow 0}C|z|^{1/2}=0$ one can conclude that $H$ has a zero order 1 , that is $H(Z)=zG(Z)$. How we can assure this has order 1 which implies that $G$ is holomorphic in $D_1$. I mean it can also happen that $H$ has a zero of order 2. That would be $H(Z)=z^2G(Z)$, and also $G(Z)$ would be holomorphic in $D_1$. Or not?

Comment: I don't like their hint. Look instead at $g(z)=z^3 f(z)$ it is holomorphic on $|z|< 1$ thus (Cauchy integral formula) it is analytic at $0$.

Comment: @reuns : Why does $h(z)$ not satisfy this property? As shown, also $h$ has a removable singularity in $z=0$, thus is also holomorphic/analytical there after continuation to $H$.

Comment: @LutzL  $g(z) = O(z^{3/2}) \implies g'(0) = 0$ this doesn't work with $z^2f(z)= O(z^{1/2})$. The removable singularity theorem follows from what I wrote.

Comment: Nevertheless, $H$ is as stated holomorphic/analytical on the whole disk. This is non-trivial, but still true, removable singularities "are not so singular after all", the only true singularities are poles and essential singularities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited text does not claim that the order of the zero at $z=0$ is one. It just says that $H$ takes the value zero there and thus the order is at least one, and so $H$ can be written as $H(z)=zG(z)$. The case $G(0)=0$ is explicitly not excluded, it is discussed one sentence further down as the second case.